Insert page break in Word document using macro in Excel
I am trying to have my macro make three tables in Word. It currently makes one big table and formats it correctly, but I can't find how to force a page break at the desired times. I found a macro that was using vba in Word and they used .InsertBreak but this keeps causing an error when I run it.
Here is my code at present. It's pieced together from a lot of sources with bits of my own chucked in there;
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdTbl As Word.Table
Dim xlSht As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Integer
Dim lCol As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim Blanks As Integer
Dim First As Integer
Dim Second As Integer

lRow = Sheets("Feedback Sheets").Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row - 2


Blanks = 0
i = 1
    Do While i <= lRow
    Set rRng = Worksheets("Feedback Sheets").Range("A" & i)

        If IsEmpty(rRng.Value) Then
        
            Blanks = Blanks + 1
            
                If Blanks = 1 Then First = i
                If Blanks = 2 Then Second = i
                
        End If
        
        i = i + 1
    Loop
'Now I know where end of each table is

Set xlSht = ActiveSheet: lCol = 5
With wdApp
  .Visible = True
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add
  With wdDoc
    Set wdTbl = .Tables.Add(Range:=.Range, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=lCol)
    With wdTbl
      .Rows(1).Range.Font.Bold = True
      .Rows(1).HeadingFormat = True
      .Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Header 1"
      If lCol > 1 Then .Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Header 2"
      If lCol > 2 Then .Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Header 3"
    End With
    With xlSht
      For r = 1 To lRow
        If (r + 1) > wdTbl.Rows.Count Then wdTbl.Rows.Add
        If r = First Then wdDoc.InsertBreak

        If r = Second Then wdDoc.InsertBreak

        For c = 1 To lCol
          wdTbl.Cell(r + 1, c).Range.Text = xlSht.Cells(r, c).Text
        Next c
      Next r
    End With
  End With
End With

Set myTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
With myTable.Borders
 .InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
 .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleDouble
End With

Set wdTbl = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set xlSht = Nothing


When I run it I get runtime error '438', object doesn't support this property or method and the Debug highlights this line;
If r = First Then wdDoc.InsertBreak
which is why I think it's the InsertBreak that is the issue.
Edit: I have now managed to get it to make three tables with page breaks after each table, but over three different documents (and probably in the most clunky way possible). When I remove the Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add line from the second and third iterations of that block of code it just creates table 3. I feel like it might have the table selected after applying the formatting and then overwriting it with the next table, but setting Set myTable = Nothing ruins everything.
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdTbl1 As Word.Table
Dim wdTbl2 As Word.Table
Dim wdTbl3 As Word.Table
Dim xlSht As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Integer
Dim lCol As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim Blanks As Integer
Dim First As Integer
Dim Second As Integer

lRow = Sheets("Feedback Sheets").Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row - 2


Blanks = 0
i = 1
    Do While i <= lRow
    Set rRng = Worksheets("Feedback Sheets").Range("A" & i)

        If IsEmpty(rRng.Value) Then
        
            Blanks = Blanks + 1
            
                If Blanks = 1 Then First = i
                If Blanks = 2 Then Second = i
                
        End If
        
        i = i + 1
    Loop
'Now I know where end of each table is

Set xlSht = ActiveSheet: lCol = 5
With wdApp
  .Visible = True
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add
  With wdDoc
    Set wdTbl1 = .Tables.Add(Range:=.Range, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=lCol)
    With wdTbl1
      .Rows(1).Range.Font.Bold = True
      .Rows(1).HeadingFormat = True
      .Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Header 1"
      If lCol > 1 Then .Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Header 2"
      If lCol > 2 Then .Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Header 3"
    End With
    With xlSht
      For r = 1 To First
        If (r + 1) > wdTbl1.Rows.Count Then wdTbl1.Rows.Add
        If r = First Then wdDoc.Characters.Last.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
        For c = 1 To lCol
          wdTbl1.Cell(r + 1, c).Range.Text = xlSht.Cells(r, c).Text
        Next c

      Next r
    End With
  End With
End With

Set myTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
With myTable.Borders
 .InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
 .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleDouble
End With


  
With wdApp
 .Visible = True
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add
  With wdDoc
    Set wdTbl2 = .Tables.Add(Range:=.Range, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=lCol)
    With wdTbl2
      .Rows(1).Range.Font.Bold = True
      .Rows(1).HeadingFormat = True
      .Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Header 1"
      If lCol > 1 Then .Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Header 2"
      If lCol > 2 Then .Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Header 3"
    End With
    With xlSht
      For r = First To Second
        If (r + 1) > wdTbl2.Rows.Count Then wdTbl2.Rows.Add

        If r = Second Then wdDoc.Characters.Last.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak

        For c = 1 To lCol
          wdTbl2.Cell(r + 1, c).Range.Text = xlSht.Cells(r, c).Text
        Next c
      Next r
    End With
  End With
End With

Set myTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
With myTable.Borders
 .InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
 .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleDouble
End With

With wdApp
 .Visible = True
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add
  With wdDoc
    Set wdTbl3 = .Tables.Add(Range:=.Range, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=lCol)
    With wdTbl3
      .Rows(1).Range.Font.Bold = True
      .Rows(1).HeadingFormat = True
      .Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Header 1"
      If lCol > 1 Then .Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Header 2"
      If lCol > 2 Then .Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Header 3"
    End With
    With xlSht
      For r = Second To lRow
        If (r + 1) > wdTbl3.Rows.Count Then wdTbl3.Rows.Add

        If r = Second Then wdDoc.Characters.Last.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak

        For c = 1 To lCol
          wdTbl3.Cell(r + 1, c).Range.Text = xlSht.Cells(r, c).Text
        Next c
      Next r
    End With
  End With
End With

Set myTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
With myTable.Borders
 .InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
 .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleDouble
End With


Set wdTbl1 = Nothing: Set wdTbl2 = Nothing: Set wdTbl3 = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set xlSht = Nothing

Edit 2: This seems to have strayed too far from the original question so I'll mark this one as done and ask a new one.

Try this and tell me:
If r = First Then wdTbl.Range.Cells(r + 1, 1).Range.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak

It highlights the .Cells now and says Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Ok. Ignore the cell and try rows:
Set rng = wdTbl.Rows(r + 1).Range then rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart and rng.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak

So I have edited it to have this now;  If r = First Then Set rng = wdTbl.Rows(r + 1).Range rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart rng.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak End If If r = Second Then Set rng2 = wdTbl.Rows(Second - First + 1).Range rng2.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart rng2.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak End If
which makes the first and third table correctly but puts the middle table on a page after a page break at the end. Very confused now

That is a different question. Probabley you are missing some breaks while creating First and Second blanks.

I've looked further, it has the First and Second at the right values, but actually only creates the one break that puts the second table at the end. Before these changes it was all appearing in the right order just with no page breaks

Pls. not make edits of your post in comment. Edit directly your post by clicking the Edit tag at the end of the question right to Share. It is hard to follow what is the actual code and the actual issue. This helps for those who can and want to answer it.

wdDoc.InsertBreak is invalid, as you would know if you're using IntelliSense, because the document object does not have an InsertBreak method.
InsertBreak is a method of the Range object. As you want to place the break after the table you should use:
wdDoc.Characters.Last.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak


This is closer to correct. It adds page breaks but not in the table, just puts two at the end of the full table.
It is taking a range over three tables in Excel that are separated by rows of blank cells and needs to create a table, reach a row of blank cell, insert a page break, and then continue making a table in Word.
Also I'm using a very slow work computer and often the IntelliSense fails to load at all so it is difficult to tell if it is invalid or just taking a long time to appear.
